# Vector ordering

Tags: arrays, sorting, vector, fortran

I have the algorithm to order a Vector `l(i)` with components in increasing order, and also I generated a vector order `D(i)`, which tells me where each component comes from, so then I can go back to the original (disordered) vector.

The order and the order vector are fine, the problem occurs when I want to go back to the original. For some reason it doesn't work, it repeats components of the vector and not in a specific order. I don't realize what it is.

Here is the code:

```
program order
  implicit none
  integer i,j,k,q
  integer l(7),D(7)
  real x


  do i=1,7
     call random_number (x)
     l(i)=1+FLOOR(13*x)
  enddo
  Write(*,*) "Without order"
  do i=1,7
     Write(*,*) l(i)
  enddo
  do i=1,7
     D(i)=i
  enddo
  
  do i=1,6
     do j=i+1,7
        if(l(i).gt.l(j))then
        k=l(i)
        l(i)=l(j)
        l(j)=k
        q=D(i)
        D(i)=D(j)
        D(j)=q
        endif
     enddo
  enddo

  Write(*,*) "Ordered"


  do i=1,7
     Write(*,*) l(i)
  enddo
  Write(*,*) "Order vector"
   do i=1,7
      Write(*,*) D(i)
   enddo
  do i=1,7
    l(D(i))=l(i)
  enddo
  Write(*,*) "The original vector is"
  do i=1,7
    Write(*,*) l(i)
  enddo

endprogram order
```

Comment: Fortran supports vector subscripts.  If `D` holds the original positions, then `I(D)` is the original order.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please explain the problem better. Do not say "it does not work", it does not say anything useful. Tell us what is wrong. Are the results incorrect? How exactly incorrect? Or is there some error message? You wrote that it happens in the last step, but what actually happens? Is the order incorrect? How incorrect? Or what is wrong?

Comment: The statement: ` l(D(i))=l(i)` will result in a situation that an element of `l` already has a replaced value but its value hasn't yet been placed somewhere back. (Note that your program doesn't compile as you didn't  declare `k` and `q`. Also I wouldn't use numbers like `6` and `7` in the code but the value of `nmax` here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean with "nota un a specific perder.". Your edit regarding replacing `nmax` with `7` is contrary to my general advise of using the numbers `6` and `7, better to use instead of `7` everywhere `nmax` and instead of `6` `nmax -1`

Answer (score 3):

As @albert points out, because your `l(D(i))=l(i)` loop overwrites `l` in-place, you are destroying information as you go. Consider the simple example

```
nmax = 2
l = [1,2]
D = [2,1]
```

Unrolling your loop gives

```
l(D(1))=l(1)
l(D(2))=l(2)
```

i.e.

```
l(2)=l(1)
l(1)=l(2)
```

and tracking the value of `l`, we see

```
! l = [1,2]
l(2)=l(1)
! l = [1,1]
l(1)=l(2)
! l = [1,1]
```

So you either need to make a copy of `l` before the loop, and work from that, or, as @steve points out, you need to do the whole thing in one operation, using a [vector subscript](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-fortran-linux/16.1.1?topic=sections-vector-subscripts), in which case the whole loop would become

```
l(D) = l
```

Indeed, it is possible to simplify most of your code using whole-array operations rather than loops, as e.g.

```
program order
  implicit none
  integer :: i,j,k,q
  integer, parameter :: nmax=7
  integer :: l(nmax),D(nmax)
  real :: x(nmax)
  
  ! Set `l` to a random vector.
  call random_number(x)
  l = 1+floor(13*x)
  
  write(*,*) "Without order"
  write(*,'(I2)') l
  
  ! Set `D` to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].
  D = [(i, i=1, nmax)]
  
  ! Sort `l` and `D` together.
  do i=1,nmax-1
    do j=i+1,nmax
      if (l(i) > l(j)) then
        ! Swap `l(i)` and `l(j)`.
        l([i,j]) = l([j,i])
        ! Swap `D(i)` and `D(j)`.
        D([i,j]) = D([j,i])
      endif
    enddo
  enddo

  write(*,*) "Ordered"
  write(*,'(I2)') l
  
  write(*,*) "Order vector"
  write(*,'(I2)') D
  
  ! Unsort `l`.
  l(D) = l
  
  write(*,*) "The original vector is"
  write(*,'(I2)') l
end program order
```

Comment: Great solution!.  I've never thought about swapping elements with the vector subscripts as you have done: `l([i,j]) = l([j,i])`.  Learned something new today!  Your code is almost identical to my WIP code, except my last line is `l = l(D)`, which gives the wrong order.

Comment: Still have the same problem :/ . Thank you @veryreverie. I used an auxiliar vector and worked!

Comment: @albert thank you too, i rewrited the code again with nmax, i originally used it but i undertood you wrong, sorry.